# How to enable embedded javascript debugger in SWT browser?

Tags: javascript, swt, firebug, xul, xulrunner

I want to embed a JavaScript debugger in a SWT browser.

I'm using the SWT.MOZILLA flag for creating the browser. Since the JavaScript application I'm loading is complex, I need to have some JS debugger (any is suitable: [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [venkman](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Venkman)).

So, is there any way to embed a JS debugger in a browser widget?

I've heard about [firebug-lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), but I don't know how to configure it in SWT. Could you give some working example?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [Using Firebug Lite in SWT Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092687/373861). The code snippet works with XULRunner 10.0.2 and Eclipse 4.2.

#### Output for XULRunner

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Guess that you should try to add the firebug code to your script tag