# Not able to debug/F12 the JSON request in SWT browser / Eclipse Development Environment

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, swt

Any Idea how to enable F12 and developer options in SWT / ECLIPSE development environement.I Want to see Java Script errors and how JSON response are being rendered in SWT browser.
 I am facing issues when passing the HTML tags with data like  Stack  in JSON at SWT browser. 
It is just an example, which can be changed at run time as per JSON response.

Comment: Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Better answer for anyone still doing this in 2024...if you're on a Windows system, you may have the "IEChooser.exe" tool that allows you to show an IE dev tools window for any running instance of IE, including the default IE browser used by SWT.  This gives you console, JS debugging, network traffic, DOM Explorer, etc, you would have gotten within IE.

Look for it here: **C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe**

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092687.

Or, you can more simply add this to your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```